# How to count the rows with the conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
 
# initialize data of lists.
data = {'name':['x', 'y', 'z'],
        'value':['fb', 'nan', 'ti']}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I now want to check the column of `value` and count the number of rows if `value` does not have 'fb' and 'nan' (null values).

How can I do this?

Comment: Is it the literal string `"nan"` or `np.nan`?

Answer (score 2):

```
df[~df.value.isin(['fb','nan'])].shape[0]
```

In this case, we are checking when the value is not in this list and selecting those rows only. From there we can get the shape using `shape` of that dataframe.

##### Output

```
1
```

This would be the result dataframe

```
  name value
2    z    ti
```

If in future you want to also ignore the rows where the `value` column is NA (NA values, such as None or numpy.NaN),then you can use this

```
df[(~df.value.isin(['fb','nan'])) &  (~df.value.isnull())].shape[0]
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I add more values to this part df.value == 'fb'? For instance, tw too?

Comment: @datazang Check it.

Comment: I think this way was great: df[df['value'].isin(value_list) &  (~df['value'].isnull())] However, I need to get its reverse. :)

Comment: @datazang Check the answer now. I have changed it to allow that or maybe refresh the page. That's why my edit was 7 min ago

Comment: Sorry, it somehow gives me 0 that is not possible in my data.

Comment: `# initialize data of lists.
data = {'name':['x', 'y', 'z'],
        'value':['fb', 'nan', 'ti']}` with this data it cant be 0?

Answer (score 0):

To count values that are not fb and nan:

```
(~df.value.str.contains('fb|nan')).sum()
```

Omit the tilde if you want to count the fb and nan values.

Comment: Thanks! I am getting this error: TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

Comment: It works as stated on my machine. It seems that your value column might contain float values?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a condition checking for `"fb"` or `NaN`, and use `sum` to get the count of True's:

```
>>> (df['value'].eq('fb') | df['value'].isna()).sum()
3
```